# Exponential Distribution Lifetime of a Lightbulb - Is my solution correct?

Tags: probability, statistics, exponential-distribution

Can someone please check if I tackled this question correctly? I don't have answers to refer to. Thank you in advance!

The lifetime of a lightbulb expressed in days is exponentially distributed with paremeter 0.004.

a) What is the probability that the lightbulb lasts at least 300 days?

So we are looking for $1-P([0,299])$.

> $P([a,b]) = e^{-\lambda a}-e^{-\lambda b}$
>
> $\lambda=0.004$
>
> $P([0,299]) = e^{-0.004 *0}-e^{-0.004*299} = 1-0.3024=0.6975$
>
> From here follows that: $P([300,∞)=1- 0.6975=0.3025$

b) What is the probability that the lightbulb lasts at most one year?

> Here we compute probability for the interval of $[0,365]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

For $a)$ you have to regard that the random variable of the lifetime of a lightbulb is continuous. That means $P(X\geq t)=1-P(X\leq t)$

For b) you just insert the value for $t=365$ into the cdf. Or you integrate the pdf:

$$P(X\leq 365)=\int_0^{365} 0.004\cdot e^{-0.004x} \, dx$$

Comment: So my solution to a) should involve 300 as well and not take into consideration only the interval of [0,299]?

Comment: @VRT That´s true.